# rails use postgresql jsonb to log user activity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I try to use jsonb data format(new feature in postgresql), to log user(interactive with devise) actives, like pageview...search string...

versions:
**Rails 4.2.6
Postgresql 9.5**

my model:

```
class CreateUserLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration   
    def self.up
      create_table :user_logs, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :user_id
        t.jsonb :data, default: '{}'
      end
      add_index :user_logs, :user_id   end   
    def self.down       
      drop_table :user_logs   
    end 
end
```

my log service object:

```
class UserLogger

  def initialize(current_user)
    @user_id = current_user.present? ? current_user.id : 0
  end

  def insert_log_data(request_ip, controller_name, action_name, object)
    user_log = UserLog.create!({
      user_id: @user_id,
      data: {
        ip_address: request_ip,
        controller_name: controller_name,
        action_name: action_name,
        id: object.id,
        created_at: Time.now.to_s(:db)
      }
    })
  end
end
```

## My target is simple analyze log data for all user and each one.

to get something like top 3 articles user like...etc.
postgresql jsonb is noSQL, a good choice for log data.

I try [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem, but when data grow bigger, the efficacy will fall.

should I put the **User_ID** in the jsonb data type too?  or another better way?(I already use **Google Analytics**, but it can't track activity by each user. I need customized data.)

But if I want to group and order data, Maybe impressionist is a better choice?